# Outlook add-in deployment - office-addin-dev-certs module bug

Tags: webpack, node-modules, render, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to deploy my office add-in on Render. I use the yoeman to generate outlook SSO code. All work fine when I am in development mode.

The problem is when I try to deploy my add-in to Render, I get this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'office-addin-dev-certs'
Require stack:
- /opt/render/project/src/dist/middletier.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at /opt/render/project/src/dist/middletier.js:2:425
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/dist/middletier.js:2:27306)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/opt/render/project/src/dist/middletier.js' ]
}
```

I have a folder:

```
src:
  middle-tier:
     app.js
     msgraph-helper.js
     ssoauth-helper.js
```

I use webpack to compile these 3 functions into a dist/middletier.js. I also include a package.json in this dist folder.

I include the module in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.28.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "4.17.3",
    "form-urlencoded": "3.0.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "office-addin-debugging": "^5.0.12",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.11.3",
    "office-addin-lint": "^2.2.5",
    "office-addin-manifest": "^1.12.3",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "9.0.0",
    "jwks-rsa": "2.1.4",
    "morgan": "1.9.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "office-addin-sso": "^2.1.13",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

and in Render I use 'npm install' on my dist root to build and then I use node middletier.js to run the server but each time I get a module error.

Could you help me please ?
Thank you.